# "Not found"-error when running my Flask/React app using gunicorn

Tags: reactjs, flask, url-routing, gunicorn, auth0

I developed an app, that uses Flask for backend and React for frontend. Also it uses the Auth0 for the authentication.

When I run it directly on my VM it works perfect, but when I try to run using the `gunicorn -b :5000 api:app` command or in container (Dockerfile is provided below), I'm still able to see the Login-Page, but after entering credentials I expect the app to be redirected to the /dashboard endpoint, but it crashes and I get a "Not Found" error.

[The Login-Page is still there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg82a.jpg)

[Login-Form from Auth0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwmfZ.png)

[404-error after entering credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Iqi4.png)

I provide the main code that I think is important.

Thank you in advance for you help. If any further information is needed just let me know.

**root/api/api.py**

```
import datetime  
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request  
from flask_cors import CORS  
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE  
from servers import stop, checkInstance  

app = Flask(`__name__`, static_folder="../build", static_url_path='/')  
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "http://localhost:3000"}})  

@app.route('/')  
def index():  
        return app.send_static_file('index.html')

#i think the code above is the reason for the error, but I'm not sure   


@app.route('/stop-server', methods=['GET'])
def stop_server():
    stop()

    with open('./output.txt', 'r') as f:
        output = f.read()

    return jsonify(output)

@app.route('/start-server', methods=['POST'])
def start_server():
    data = request.get_json()
    run_datetime = data['datetime']

    #Format the datetime string
    run_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(run_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    run_datetime_str = run_datetime.strftime('%H:%M %m/%d/%Y')

    #Execute the start command using the `at` command and redirect stderr to /dev/null
    cmd = f'echo "python ./start_script.py" | at {run_datetime_str} 2>/dev/null'
    p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

    if stderr:
        return jsonify(f'Error scheduling server start: {stderr.decode()}')

    return jsonify('Server start scheduled successfully')

@app.route('/status', methods=['GET'])
def status():
    output = checkInstance()
    return jsonify(output)

if name == 'main':
    app.run()
```

**root/src/App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Server from './components/Server';
import Login from './components/Login';
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute';

const App = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated, isLoading, loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/dashboard' element={<PrivateRoute component={Server}/>} />
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Login/>} />
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**root/src/index.js**

```
import { Auth0Provider } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import config from './auth_config.json';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Auth0Provider
    domain={config.domain}
    clientId={config.clientId}
    authorizationParams={{
      redirect_uri: 'https://best.**********.de/dashboard'
    }}
  >
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Auth0Provider>,
);
```

**root/Dockerfile**

```
#Build step 1

FROM node:latest as build-step
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./public ./public
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
    
    
#Build step 2

FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build-step /app/build ./build
RUN mkdir ./api

COPY api/requirements.txt api/api.py api/.flaskenv api/output.txt api/servers.py api/start_script.py      ./api/
RUN pip install -r ./api/requirements.txt
ENV FLASK_ENV production

EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR /app/api
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", ":3000", "api:app"]
```

**root/package.json (just one important line)**

`"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"`

**directories tree**

```
.
└── react-flask-app
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── api
    │   ├── api.py
    │   ├── output.txt
    │   ├── requirements.txt
    │   ├── servers.py
    │   ├── start_script.py
    │   └── venv/
    ├── build
    │   ├── build-files
    │   └── static
    │       ├── css
    │       ├── js
    │       └── media
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── public
    └── src
        ├── App.css
        ├── App.js
        ├── auth_config.json
        ├── components
        │   ├── Login.js
        │   ├── Logout.js
        │   ├── PrivateRoute.js
        │   ├── Server.js
        ├── index.css
        ├── index.js
```

I tried to rewrite gunicorn command, I changed the paths, ran on different ports but it didn't work :(